# Vertically align text within a textbox when AutoSize=false

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, custom-controls, controls

I'm trying to extend the standard TextBox control in the System.Windows.Forms namespace.  One of the things I'm trying to accomplish is to modify padding on the top and bottom of the TextBox (the spacing between the text and the border).

Doing it on the left/right sides is pretty simple, but I'm having a hard time getting anything to work on the top/bottom.

Here are a couple of my requirements (if possible):

- Avoid extending anything besides `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` (no UserControls)
- I want to keep `MultiLine` = `false`

This code allows me to resize vertically, and it adds a left padding:

```
public class TextBoxTest : TextBox
{
    public TextBoxTest()
    {
        base.AutoSize = false;
        NativeMethods.SendMessage(Handle, NativeMethods.EM_SETMARGINS, NativeMethods.EC_LEFTMARGIN, 20);

        base.Height = 55;
        base.Width = 150;
        base.Text = "This is a test";
    }
}
```

This will look like:

[image]

I also tried `EM_SETRECT` but it requires a MultiLine TextBox.

Is a top/bottom margin (or center vertically) possible - without using a UserControl and keeping MultiLine=false?

If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

UPDATE, to clarify, the reason I want to inherit from TextBox, and not a UserControl or Panel is so it passes the duck test (if it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, etc).  I want `if (myControl is TextBox) ...` to evaluate to true.  There may be a way to do that, I haven't done much with Type Converters and maybe that's the path I should be taking.

I want this to be a true extension of a TextBox. In other words, it can do just about everything a textbox can do plus some, but no limitations due to the fact that it's not of type "TextBox".  It seems like there's gotta be a way to adjust it somehow, it supports left and right margins but seemingly not upper/lower margins.  Thanks again

Comment: Why not make it multi line and prevent the enter key? Just a suggestion though

Comment: Thanks Ronald, I will need to think about that a little bit, like wat other behavioral differences occur when `MultiLine=true`?  That's more of a rhetorical question for myself...

Comment: yea thats one thing you'd have to figure out too, just spurring out alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the padding property of Windows forms textbox from your code.

Instead you can place a textbox in a container, like a panel
remove the border of the textbox, make sure that the `BackColor` property for both is same
change the `Dock` property of the textbox to `Fill`
and then apply padding to the panel.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but one of the things I want to try to accomplish is to keep it from showing as type UserControl or Panel.   I added an update to my question (last 2 paragraphs) to explain why I want it to inherit from TextBox... I mean, if it's possible at all.

Comment: It can still do what a textbox can do. Well, obviously it is a textbox lol. But it will seem like the textbox has some vertical padding. Why do you want vertical padding anyway?